# If combobox1 and combobox2 is true then update the items in combobox3

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox

I want to add new items/change the items in cmbSection if cmbCourse, cmbYear and cmbSems met the requirements. I try this code but cmbSection won't add new items/change the items.

```
private void AddNewStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbCourse.SelectedItem.Equals("BSIT"))
        {
            if (cmbYear.SelectedItem.Equals("1st"))
            {
                if (cmbSems.SelectedItem.Equals("1st"))
                {
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT101C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT102C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT103C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT104C");
                }
                else if (cmbSems.SelectedItem.Equals("2nd"))
                {
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT201C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT202C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT203C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT204C");
                }
            }
            else if (cmbYear.SelectedItem.Equals("2nd"))
            {
                if (cmbSems.SelectedItem.Equals("1st"))
                {
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT301C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT302C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT303C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT304C");
                }
                else if (cmbSems.SelectedItem.Equals("2nd"))
                {
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT401C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT402C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT403C");
                    cmbSection.Items.Add("IT404C");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged the program at all?  Do you know if this method is even being called when you want?  If the method isn't being called, use an Event such as SelectedIndexChanged to trigger it when the values change.  If the method is being called but the Equality check is failing you likely need to use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use event in C#.
You register event SelectedIndexChanged of cmbCourse ==> When cmbCourse changed selected index, you will load new data into cmbYear. 
You register event SelectedIndexChanged of cmbYear==> When cmbYear changed selected index, you will load new data into cmbSems.

You register event SelectedIndexChanged of cmbSems==> When cmbSems changed selected index, you will load new data into cmbSection.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking all the conditions when the form loads; I assume you want to check it when the user changes the option in one of the combo boxes, in which case, as tauitdnmd stated, `SelectedIndexChanged` is the event you should be using, not `Form.Load`. You can set the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for each ComboxBox to all be handled by a single method, i.e., the one you have (although I strongly recommend a name change).

However, if you were to simply change which event is being handled, the use of `Items.Add` would result in the new options being added along side the old ones, quickly creating an enormously long and redundant drop-down. The solution to this is simply clearing each ComboBox in question before adding all the relevant options with `Items.Clear()`.

@Vulcronos: I created a test application with the same code, only with a button click as the event, and the `SelectedItem.Equals()` check appears to works fine (the validity of its use notwithstanding).